# Asp Net Core 3.1 write and read JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I want to write data to a json file and read the data. However, the data in my json file is dynamic and may vary. I do not know what to use for this. Can you help?

My Json file is as follows:

```
{
  "IpAddress": ".....",
  "Port": 5000,
  .....
  "tracks": {
    "audio1": "track1.mp3"
    "audio2": "track2.mp3"
    .....
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass json data to action?Maybe you can use Object in action.

Answer (score 1):

Use Nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json`.

[Code samples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm) | [Official site](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

After you get `json` string, you can write it to file [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/read-write-text-file) or send it, or something else.

Also, very important, to not write `c#` models by yourself, you can use [this service](https://json2csharp.com/) to convert `json` to `c#` model and `c#` model to `json`.

Comment: why is it very important not to write by ourselves?

Comment: @SahinYanlık The time of a self-respecting developer is expensive

Answer (score 1):

I tried as below to read a json file and modify the content and write to another  Json file:

```
            JObject jObj;
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("newjson.json"))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                jObj = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);   
            }

            var tracks = new track(){audio= "track3.mp3" };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tracks);
            jObj["tracks"] = JObject.Parse(json);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("anotherjson.json"))
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
            {
                jObj.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
            }
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to pass dynamic json data to action:

request:

[image]

action:

```
public IActionResult Index5([FromBody]Object o)
        {
            return Ok(o);
         }
```

the result of `Object o`:

[image: ![strong text]

Comment: If we saw the local port of your application, the consequences would be terrible!

Comment: `Port :5000` is the data in json,as `Elchin` shown in his json file.

Comment: So, what is reason to hide port in postman? XD